# I want to add another line but it has the same variable but different paramaters

Tags: java

I am very new to this. 1 day old. Trying to modify some code to read another formatting option.

```
public enum GeoFormat {
        L2J("%d_%d.l2j"),
        L2OFF("%d_%d_conv.dat"),
        L2D("%d_%d.l2d"), 
        L2D("%d_%d_Classic.l2d");
```

I want to add the bottom line so that it still read the L2D but in a different format as there are different formatting options for it.

Comment: Just name it something different. `L2DClassic` or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `L2D("%d_%d_Classic.l2d");` to `L2DCLASSIC("%d_%d_Classic.l2d");` - You can't have two enumerated constants of the same name.